# Mixing model-bound and non-model-bound fields in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a form in my Rails app that passes its data to a third party (Stripe) without a model.  However, my client now wants the same form to include other fields that are persisted.  How do I create a form that submits model bound and non-model-bound fields?

Comment: You can just create the stripe fields with raw HTML. Stripe doesn't want you to set `name` attributes on the fields in order to prevent the field data from being submitted. The validation for these fields must be done client-side anyway, so there is really zero benefit to tying the stripe fields into rails `form_for`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Stripe, but you can easily include non-database-bound attributes in the model using 'attr_accessor'.

in your model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :stripe_attribute_one, :stripe_attribute_two
end
```

in your form

```
# assuming your model has migrated attributes called :db_attribute_one and :db_attribute_two
<%= form_for @my_model %>
  <%= f.text_field :db_attribute_one %>
  <%= f.text_field :db_attribute_two %>
  <%= f.text_field :stripe_attribute_one %>
  <%= f.text_field :stripe_attribute_two %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is ugly because the attributes are never used by Rails. Modifying the model for the sole purpose of rendering a set of fields via rails form helpers is confusing and unnecessary. Further, you still have to unset the name attribute on each form field, whether via these helpers or via Javascript. It's a requirement for Stripe forms https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms For these reasons, plain HTML is simpler.

Comment: @Deefour, can you elaborate on what you mean by "unset the name attribute"?

Comment: Read the docs in the link of my original comment above. The reason you're allowed to accept cards on your SSL-less site is because you're not passing any card info over the wire when using stripe.js. To prevent card info from being sent with a form submission you need to remove/unset the `name="..."` attribute from the card fields.

Comment: See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field); you may be able to set `name: nil` or similar as an option. But for me this sort of defeats the purpose of the helper and is why I suggest just using raw HTML.